# Yii / gii code generator customization : how to reuse the default templates?

Tags: php, yii, gii

I am starting to play with the [Code Generators](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) provided by the [Gii module](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/GiiModule#generatorPaths-detail).

I want to customize some of the CRUD generated files. The CRUD code generator stands in `framework/gii/generators/crud` and the files I'm interested in are under the `templates/default` sub-directory.

Now, let's say I want to customize `_view.php`.

I copy-paste all the files from
`framework/gii/generators/crud/templates/default` to `protected/gii/crud/templates/mytemplates`, update the `_view.php` file, go to the Gii crud generation page, select my Model, Controller and code template, click on preview and voila: the generators builds the files.

Now, let's say **the only file I'll ever customize here is`_view.php`**. I don't like so much duplicating files and do nothing with them. Instead, I'd like to find a way to **reuse the existing default files**.

So: is there any way to tell to the Code Generator "hey! when you don't find a template file, just go to the default directory where they are stored as usual." ?

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the CodeGenerator to look for fallback files, but that's some work to do.

A quicker (but more hackish) workaround could be just to include the original views from the views in *mytemplates*. Just put this in the view files you want to reference (eg. `mytemplates/list.php`):

```
<?php

include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../default/".basename(__FILE__));
```

Note: I haven't tested this in gii, but went with the same approach in themes, which worked fine. The drawback is that you have to create a file for every template you want to reference.